Kuon Zodiac Puzzle Tactics?

https://youtu.be/tZTNck3RhPE
It's a 4x3 sliding puzzle with no free space where you can only move an entire row or column at a time, you can only move them forwards and the pieces loop around.
Any tips for solving it? In game it's easily completed because there's a fixed starting orientation but I'm curious as to how I could solve it if it were scrambled.

Take a look at this previous post which seems to answer your question.

This puzzle can be solved in a few short steps, once you know where every block needs to be:

 1) Get the top four blocks in the correct order.
 2) Get the middle four blocks in the correct order, using the bottom row as extra space.
 3) Set a specific column to be your "pusher", and use 3-cycles to reorder the bottom row. Pushing down a symbol A, pulling up a symbol B, pushing down a symbol C, then pulling up the pusher's original middle will cycle the positions of A, B, and C.

